# How do we “buy” from Jesus in Revelation 3:18?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 3:18 NASB

> “I advise you to *buy* from Me gold refined by fire so that you may become rich, and white garments so that you may clothe yourself, and that the shame of your nakedness will not be revealed; and eye salve to anoint your eyes so that you may see.”
> ‭‭

How does one “buy” these things from Jesus? Why did He use that word?

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than it appears.  In Rev 3:18, how does one deal with the apparent contradiction to those in Laodicea who think they are rich but are

> Rev 3:17 - You say, ‘I am rich; I have grown wealthy and need
> nothing.’ But you do not realize that you are **wretched, pitiful,
> poor, blind, and naked**.

That is, how does one who is poor buy anything?

The answer is rather simple because this text alludes to Isa 55:1 -

> “Come, all you who are thirsty, come to the waters; and you without
> money, come, buy, and eat! Come, buy wine and milk **without money and
> without cost**!

We should recall that God's grace is completely free.

> Eph 2:8-10 - For it is **by grace** you have been saved through faith,
> and this not from yourselves; it is **the gift of God**, not by works,
> so that no one can boast. For we are God’s workmanship, created in
> Christ Jesus to do good works, which God prepared in advance as our
> way of life.